# Program to find the max and biggest negative number

Tags: c

The following code prints the maximum and the biggest negative value (if we have -10 and -5, -5 is bigger) of numbers entered unitl a symbol is reached. My question is if there is a better way to find the largest negative value (avoiding INT_MIN or other clumsy ways of this kind).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <limits.h>
int main()
{
    float max=0, n, bnn=INT_MIN;
    while(1){
        printf("Enter an integer:");
        if(scanf("%f", &n)!=1){
            break;
        }
        if (n>max)
            max=n;
        else if(n>=bnn)
             bnn=n;
    }
    printf("The maximum number of the entered ones is:%0.2f\n", max);
    printf("The biggest negative number is:%0.2f", bnn);
    getch();
}
```

Comment: What is clumsy about `INT_MIN`?

Comment: Calling the max neg value "min" is a poor choice. As for ways to implement it, this is common.

Comment: If you're only interested in the largest negative number, shouldn't you be checking whether `n` is negative before comparing to the previous value?  But yes, you will need to start with some large negative number, so `INT_MIN` seems pretty reasonable.

Comment: Your "min" is not being constrained to be negative

Comment: Why are you mixing float and int?

Comment: Also, why the "else"?  The largest number may also be the largest negative number.

Comment: The alternative to using something like INT_MIN is to set the variable to the first value, possibly using a flag to determine whether that has been done yet. The way you're doing it is far *less* clumsy. (However, as noted in the comments here, you're doing several *other* things wrong.)

Comment: Oh, you also print the wrong thing -- `bnn` instead of `min` (which, as I noted, is not a min value). You've been extremely sloppy here ... programming needs precision and attention to detail.

Comment: Assuming an IEEE-754 floating point implementation (which is nearly universal), you could start with `-FLT_MAX` to avoid mixing `INT_MIN` and floats.

Comment: Or even better in C99: `-INFINITY`.

Comment: @Matt B.  Like the `-INFINITY`.  Now for something completely different.  Could set `max=NAN` or `max=0.0/0.0` and then do `if (!(n<=max)) max=n;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start bnn at 0.0  Then

```
if ((n < 0) && ((bnn == 0.0) || (n > bnn)))
  bnn = n;
```

Comment: Is it necessary to use **|| (n > bnn)))**, I think it would run properly without it.

Comment: no, because then bnn would just be the first negative number, not the largest.

Answer (score 1):

Fun with NaN.

Comparing with [Not-A-Number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not-a-number) always returns false.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main() {
  float max = 0.0 / 0.0;  // NaN
  float bnn = 0.0 / 0.0;
  while (1) {
    float n;
    printf("Enter a number:");
    if (scanf("%f", &n) != 1) {
      break;
    }
    if (!(n <= max))
      max = n;
    // if by "biggest", OP means most negative
    // if ((n < 0.0) && (!(n <= bnn)))
    // if by "biggest", OP means greatest
    if ((n < 0.0) && (!(n >= bnn)))
      bnn = n;
  }
  printf("The maximum number of the entered ones is:%0.2f\n", max);
  printf("The biggest negative number is:%0.2f\n", bnn);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: My compiler give errors on the first two float lines: Error 2 error C2124: divide or mod by zero.
Without the devision the program will find the least of the negative numbers, not the biggest one.